# Resolution problem in QGIS raster

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution

I have a raster file I need to clip. I created a virtual raster which I used to "copy" the extent from in QGIS raster calculator. As a result, I get the raster with the extent I need, but pixel size changes and it looks fuzzy compared with the original raster...
Does anyone know how to avoid or correct this problem?

The first printscreen shows the original raster:
[image] 
The second printscreen shows the raster after beeing clipped:

[image]

Comment: How did you clip it? I would use GDAL_Translate -projwin (if you know the coordinates of the extents) or -srcwin (if you know rows/columns you need) to clip a raster, that will not affect the cellsize just the dimension.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't change the cell size dimensions, but it gave me a different extents in each raster, even when I used the batch mode :(

Comment: So you have the same -projwin and you're getting different extents? Are the cell sizes for each raster the same? projwin uses some rounding to calculate a srcwin and then clips using that (you can see it when the tool runs) if you want exact cells try to work out minRow,minCol maxRow,maxCol and use -srcwin, that way you control implicitly which cells are in the output... it's a bit of work but it's worth it!

Comment: Yes,I'm getting different extents and every raster has the same cell size. I will try to look on how to get the minRow,minCol maxRow,maxCol  and keep trying. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to use the Clip Tool in QGIS is by using the "extent clipping mode". For example, I want to clip the area represented by the shapefile in the next image:

[image]

With **Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper**, put the output name raster and select its area by drag on shapefile area. Then, click on Ok.

[image]

At the layer properties of the clipped raster you can observe that the X and Y pixel size is the same of the original raster (see below image). Furthermore, they are perfectly aligned (you can observe that with transparency at the first layer).

[image]

Comment: Por los printscreens veo que hablas español... intenté usar el clipper de esa manera anteriormente y no me funcionó... el extent de una de las capas quedo parecido pero no igual al de mi shape... estoy usando coordenadas geográficas y no UTM, crees que eso pueda ser un problema?

Comment: Yes, it could be the problem. You should use a projection in meters.